# How to query timestamp set as long in Gemfire?

Tags: timestamp, gemfire

```
public class Employee {
   private String name; 
   private long timestamp; 
}
```

timestamp is saved in long format. When converted it will be 2021-11-19T21:00:37.353+0000

User inputs just 2021-11-19, how can we query ignoring time/timezone and what is the correct way to query date?

**Gemfire query**

```
select * from /employee where to_date(timestamp) = to date(2021-21-19)

Error -> Query is invalid due to error - Syntax error in query - unexpected token-timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your query expression is wrong. According to the [Preset Query Functions](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/developing/query_select/the_select_statement.html#concept_85AE7D6B1E2941ED8BD2A8310A81753E__section_69DCAD624E9640028BC86FD67649DEB2) within the documentation, the `TO_DATE` function expects two parameters: the actual value to parse and the string format to be used when transforming the `String` into a `Date` using the `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` class.

I'm not sure whether there's a [supported format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to use in your case, though, so you might need to do something extra within your domain object or the `OQL` itself in order to get the `Date` representation from the `timestamp` field.

Cheers.